# Java incompatible type for type parameter in presence of wildcards

Tags: java, generics

I have following classes. I'm not able to satisfy the generic types.
Please help me understand the issue.

```
// Requirement is that each implementation of MappedKey should also be sortable. Hence should implement Comparable<ConcreteType>.
public interface MappedKey<T extends MappedKey<T>> extends Comparable<T> {
  String displayName();
}
```

```
public interface DataMapper<K extends MappedKey<K>, V> {
  ImmutableMap<K, ImmutableList<V>> map(List<V> data, Message config);
}
```

```
// Call site
Map<MapperType, DataMapper<?, Country>> mappers = getMappers();
ImmutableMap<? extends MappedKey<?>, ImmutableList<Country>> mapped = mappers.get(MAPPER_TYPE).map(getData());

// Here I want to sort the keys returned by mapper. 
List<MappedKey<?>> keys = new ArrayList<>(mapped.keySet()); // Note that this doesn't throw error because type parameter K in DataMapper definition extends MappedKey<K>.


Collections.sort(keys);
```

On running I get below error. My reasoning is that types are satisfied. Since `MappedKey<?>` implements `Comparable<? super T#1>`, `T#1 = MappedKey<?>` satisfy all constraint. What am I missing here? Thank you

```
no suitable method found for sort(List<MappedKey<?>>)
    Collections.sort(keys);
               ^
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: MappedKey<?>
        upper bounds: CAP#1,Comparable<? super T#1>)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Comparable<CAP#1> from capture of ?
```

---

Error on trying what @Sweeper suggested in the later half of his/her answer.

```
List<? extends MappedKey<?>> keys = sort(new ArrayList<>(rowMapped.keySet()));
                                        ^
  required: List<MappedKey<K>>
  found:    ArrayList<CAP#1>
  reason: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: MappedKey<K>
    lower bounds: CAP#2
  where K,E are type-variables:
    K extends MappedKey<K> declared in method <K>sort(List<MappedKey<K>>)
    E extends Object declared in class ArrayList
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends MappedKey<?> from capture of ? extends MappedKey<?>
    CAP#2 extends MappedKey<?> from capture of ? extends MappedKey<?>
```

Comment: In the second line in the call site, you say `ImmutableMap<K, ImmutableList<V>> mapped`. Where is `K` and `V` declared?

Comment: `?` means what it means - it doesn't magically update itself to the effective bounds of the thing you're using ? for. This is unfortunate, but, as far as I know, a java limitation. You may have to just accept it here, cast to a raw type, and sort from there - and use `@SuppressWarnings` to get rid of the warning this cast would cause.

Comment: My bad. Fixed it now @Sweeper